Current attracting moving/static particle, the relativity approach
I just saw a video that tries to explain magnetism (to an extent) though relativity. The idea is that you have a moving particle that is attracted to a wire with current. The explanation is that, in the free electrons reference frame the nuclei are moving and not the electrons of the wire (lets say free and the wire's electrons are moving on the same speed). Thus, due to space contraction, the positive charges appear closer together and thus the wire attracts the free electron.

BUT, if the electron was not moving at all,  from it's reference frame the nuclei are static (and retain their distance) but the   the wires electrons are moving and thus should be contracted. Similarly to the case above, they should appear more dense and the wire should repel the free electron, which is not the case.

You are misunderstanding. In the lab frame where the wire is not moving, the electrons in the wire are setup so that the charge from the electrons cancel the charge of the stationary ions. This means that from the point of view of the electrons in the wire, the wire is charged.
